# AWS claims that RDS sync replication to standby instance protects against data loss

Tags: amazon-web-services, synchronization, rds

Anyone knows what AWS uses to do RDS DB instance sync. replication? DRBD or any other low level device block transfer or something else?
cause there are situations where the standby DB instance fails when a failure occurs on master/primary DB instance?

Note: claimed in RDS section "AWS Cloud Practitioner Essentials (Second Edition): AWS Integrated Services" digital training video

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AWS utilizes database physical and logical database replication as appropriate for them.

[As per the official documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/details/multi-az/)

> Multi-AZ deployments for the MySQL, MariaDB, Oracle, and PostgreSQL
>   engines utilize synchronous physical replication to keep data on the
>   standby up-to-date with the primary. Multi-AZ deployments for the SQL
>   Server engine use synchronous logical replication to achieve the same
>   result, employing SQL Server-native Mirroring technology. Both
>   approaches safeguard your data in the event of a DB Instance failure
>   or loss of an Availability Zone.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Official slide shows that RDS actually utilizes DRBD for physical replication.

https://www.slideshare.net/AmazonWebServices/amazon-rds-with-amazon-aurora-aws-public-sector-summit-2016